# How to convert one of multiarray into a class

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have a problem similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532660/converting-two-dimensional-array-to-an-object-c-sharp).
But the difference is, mine is a var and on this example is a class.

```
var debugExe = requete.List();
```

I have tried this:

```
 var tester = debugExe[0] as IEnumerable<Client>;
 IList<Client> temp = tester.ToList<Client>();
```

My var tester is null, debugExe is not null.

type of debuxExe : [image]

List() return 2 dimension array.

Comment: Are you sure `debugExe` is not null? ie. `var debugExe = requete.List();` is not null

Comment: What does `List()` return?

Comment: What is the type of `requete`? If you hover over `var` before `debugExe`, what is the type of `debugExe`? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve ('it is like this other problem' is not sufficient)?

Comment: Unless List() returns a list of ienumerables or a list of lists, your problem is quite simple. Does `requete.List()` returns a list of Client instances? Because then your problem is that you cast a Client to IEnumerable<Client>. Is this what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

To fill an object with something that implement `IEnumerable` you can try:

```
var temp = new List<Client>(debugExe);
```

In this way you will have an empty but querable list.